# Azure website publishing to multiple instances

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an azure web site with several instances.

When I need to publish, how can I be sure that azure is publishing to each of the instances. When I publish I am doing it from Visual Studio...

When I do publish, does each instance get updated in parallel or sequentially?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all updated in parallel.

A bit more detail: Your site is actually stored on blob storage, and all instances read the same blob storage location to run your site. This means that when the contents of the blob are changed then all of your sites reflect the changes immediately.